# NodeJS. Cannot get Credentials after auth login on client-side of React

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, cookies, express-session

I trying to understand what is the wrong with my `credetrials` inside my server code, because when I make Login from the client side, the `credetrials` does not recorgonizes inside the `router.get('/auth/login')` method, but when I do the same login action by the **Postman** with `POST` method and then reload the page with `GET` method the `credetrials` recorgonizes normally and I got the message, that I already `loggined`.

So, I actually want to say, that I do not have any problem with loginnig from the client side by "POST" method for `router.post('/auth/login')`, as for logs - user info transmits normally and credentials also creates, but on `router.get('/auth/login')`  it does not callbacks in the                 `res.json({session: req.session.userId, session2: req.session, log: 'You already logined!'});`, where I gets just empty string...

My server code:

```
'use strict'
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
const session = require('express-session');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

const app = express();
const router = express.Router();

const EmployersSchemaDB = require('./SchemaDB/EmployersSchemaDB');
const User = require('./SchemaDB/ShemaAuthtificaion');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://myDB');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,PUT,DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers');
    res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
    next();
});

app.use(session({
    secret: 'work hard',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection })
}));

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json('Hello on Homepage!');
});

router
    .get('/auth/login', (req, res) => {
        User.find((err, users) => {
            if (err) { res.send(err) }
            if (req.session.userId !== undefined) { // there is where I always falls...
                res.json({session: req.session.userId, session2: req.session, log: 'You already logined!'});
            } else {
                console.log('User credentials!:', req.session.userId);
                res.json({session: req.session.userId, session2: req.session});
                console.log('---===--- \n Employers showed!: \n', users + '\n ---===---');
            }
        });
    })
    .post('/auth/login', (req, res, next) => {
        if (req.body.password !== req.body.passwordConf) {
            var err = new Error('Passwords do not match.');
            err.status = 400;
            res.send("passwords dont match");
            return next(err);
        }

        if (req.body.email &&
            req.body.username &&
            req.body.password &&
            req.body.passwordConf) {

            let user = new User();

            user.email = req.body.email;
            user.username = req.body.username;
            user.password = req.body.password;
            user.passwordConf = req.body.passwordConf;

            user.save((err) => {
                if (err) { res.send(err) }

                res.json({ message: 'Comment successfully added!', user });
                console.log('---===--- \n Employer added: \n', user + '\n ---===---');
            });  
        } else if (req.body.logemail && req.body.logpassword) {
            User.authenticate(req.body.logemail, req.body.logpassword, function (error, user) {
                if (error || !user) {
                var err = new Error('Wrong email or password.');
                err.status = 401;
                return next(err);
              } else { // this is the where credentials are creates. All work good! 
                req.session.userId = user._id;
                console.log('Signed Cookies: ', req.session.userId, req.signedCookies)
                console.log('User logined and redirected!');
                return res.redirect('/employers');
              }
            });
        } else {
            var err = new Error('All fields required.');
            err.status = 400;
            return next(err);
        }
    });

app.use('/', router);

const port = process.env.API_PORT || 3016;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});
```

My client code (just for info) : **UPDATED FOR KEVIN**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

class LoginPage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            navigate: false
        }
    }

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        let userLogin = {
            logemail: e.target.email.value,
            logpassword: e.target.password.value
        }

        axios.post('http://localhost:3016/auth/login', userLogin)
            .then(function(){
                axios.get('http://localhost:3016/auth/login', {withCredentials: true})
                    .then(res => console.log(res.data))
                    .catch(err => console.log(err)); 
                this.setState({
                    navigate: true
                })
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.error(err);
            });
    };
    render() {
        // if (this.state.navigate) {
        //   return <Redirect to="/employers" />
        // }
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                    <input name="email" type="email" className="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email" />
                    <small id="emailHelp" className="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                    <input name="password" type="password" className="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password" />
                </div>
                <div className="form-check">
                    <input type="checkbox" className="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1" />
                    <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>
        )
    }
}

export default LoginPage;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a cross domain problem as you can login successfully with Postman.

AJAX calls will not send cookies in CORS environment by default. You need to set the **withCredentials** field of **XMLHttpRequest** object as **true** to send cookies even cross domain. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials) is the official document.

As you are using **axios**, hope this setting would be helpful.

> axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

**Update**:

Please update your client code and make sure **GET /auth/login** are requested after **POST /auth/login** are completed, otherwise the **Get** request might be sent while **POST** request has not complete authenticate and set session. I recommend you change your code like following (put **Get** request after **POST** request are resolved):

```
axios.post('http://localhost:3016/auth/login', userLogin)
        .then(function(){
            axios.get('http://localhost:3016/auth/login').then(res => console.log(res.data).catch(e => console.log(e)); 
            this.setState({
                navigate: true
            })
         })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
        });
```

```

Comment: Thank you, I try this, but it not hep (... Still undefined response for GET method by axios...

Comment: Please open the chrome develop tool and and focus on the login request, and see if this request was sent along with any **Cookie** header, we need to verify if this setting works and find out the reason why session not work.

Comment: yes, the new setting's is work and I'm getting the cookies data, but without the cookies string included. So, this is what I gets now if try to request the `req.session` on `GET` method: `cookie
:
expires
:
null
httpOnly
:
true
originalMaxAge
:
null
path
:
"/" `

Comment: I updated my client code as you want, but still undefined... This is something crazy... The console.log result is the same as above in my comment

Comment: Have you checked the request headers from chrome develop tool or you can log the **req.cookies** and **req.header('cookie')** from server side?

Comment: So, I resolve my error just by adding the {withCredentials: true} for the `POST` request in my client side code and now my credentials are resives back with `GET` requst normally. So, thank you a lot, without you I probably would not have found the answer! 

Cheers!!